# Error in using IF EXISTS in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

This is my query, but I am getting an error. Please help how to do it

```
declare @spid varchar(20)

if exists ((select @spid = Sponsor_Id  from UserTransaction)  where User_id= 'RL0814')
   insert into UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id, User_Id) 
   values (@spid,'RL4108')
```

The error is:

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @spid VARCHAR(20)
SET @spid = NULL

SELECT @spid = Sponsor_Id 
FROM dbo.UserTransaction 
WHERE User_id = 'RL0814'

IF @spid IS NOT NULL
   INSERT INTO dbo.UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id, User_Id) 
   VALUES (@spid, 'RL4108')
```

Comment: I need to store the result of the select statement in a variable,@spid, and then insert

Comment: @sumedha: OK, changed my response to meet your needs - in that case, just `SELECT` that value, and if it's `NULL`, then it doesn't exist, so you cannot insert. If it's `NOT NULL`, you can insert

Comment: Thanks,but is there no way I can use if exists..doing the same?

Comment: @sumedha: no, if you need to actually **get the value**, you cannot use `IF EXISTS`